# finding the largest number of something SQL

Tags: sql

So the task is this: The database contains just 5 songs released in 1953. What is the largest number of
songs released in a single year?

And these are the columns that im working with from the table songs

songid - title - releasedate

My solution so far is this:

```
select extract(year from S.releasedate), count(S.releasedate) as most_freq
from songs S
group by extract(year from S.releasedate)
order by count(extract(year from S.releasedate)) DESC;
```

and the result is right but i was asked to only return the number 833 (that is the largest number of songs released in one year) and use another way than order by... any suggestions

this is my result:
[image]

Comment: I'd try `ORDER BY most_freq DESC` instead.

Comment: And add a `FETCH FIRST` at the end.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: pgAdmin. the most freq column is created by me: count(S.releasedate) as most_freq

Comment: which counts the times each year appears in the releasedate column and orders it

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the highest count of releases this should work:

```
select extract(count(S.releasedate) as most_freq
from songs S
group by extract(year from S.releasedate)
order by most_freq DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Convert(Varchar(4),releasedate, 120), count(releasedate) as most_freq
from songs
group by releasedate
order by count(releasedate) DESC;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a way I thought of without using the Order by clause that should work.

```
with My_CTE (year, count)
as(
select extract(year from S.releasedate), count(S.releasedate)
from songs S
group by extract(year from S.releasedate) 
) 
select max(my_cte.count)
from My_CTE
```